# PHP 8 not revealing short_open_tag setting

Tags: php, php-8, php-shorttags

The following returns a string length of zero:

```
<?php
print_r(ini_get('short_open_tag'));
?>
```

On two PHP 8 servers (apache2handler and cgi-fcgi) I need to know if short tags are enabled or not because it creates a conflict with XML. I can't afford to stop everything I'm doing to go look at `phpinfo()`.

This code worked just fine in PHP 7.4 on both servers. Now, I do know that short tags *are disabled* though I need to be able to quickly know after server upgrades.

How do I get `ini_get('short_open_tag')` working again?

Comment: That setting was completely removed in PHP 8: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_php_short_tags

Comment: @ChrisHaas That RFC was initially accepted, but then reverted. No change to short open tags is mentioned in [the PHP 8 migration guide](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php).

Comment: Thanks @IMSoP, I missed that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although this is a boolean setting, `ini_get` does in fact [return a string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php#refsect1-function.ini-get-notes).

> **Note: When querying boolean values**
>
> A boolean ini value of `off` will be returned as an empty string or "0" while a boolean ini value of `on` will be returned as "1". The function can also return the literal string of INI value.

So when the feature is enabled, it will return "1" which you can use to check the status of the setting. (Despite the last sentence in that note, I've never seen any literal values such as "on" or "off" returned for boolean values.)

```php
var_dump(ini_get('short_open_tag'));
```

Output with the setting enabled:

```
string(1) "1"
```

---

A little history: although there was [a vote taken](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_php_short_tags) to remove these tags, it was overturned. The chief concern was with legacy code that would have been displayed to end users when the server was upgraded – the same reason the setting continues to default to "On" despite its use being discouraged [for decades](https://web.archive.org/web/20020601214529/http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php). After the meltdown over the first RFC, [a subsequent proposal](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_php_short_tags_v2) that made short open tags an error condition did not receive the required 2/3 majority to pass.

Comment: I feel dirty for having enabled that setting for 2 minutes to test. ;)

Comment: HA! I will return back to this question; thought it had been resolved though thank you for going out of your way to comment on one of my earlier questions. I'll be testing this shortly...uh, no pun intended. ︀

Comment: No worries, I also thought the feature had been removed, but feeding a non-existent setting to `ini_get()` always returns boolean false. So I was in the middle of testing it when your question disappeared.

Comment: So `var_dump(ini_get('short_open_tag'));` returns `(string(0) "" )` and I'm at a loss as what to do now. I get the reasoning behind the overturn even though I can't seem to figure out where it's located...though I still have an empty string. Granted this is only for my Administrative overview (not webmasters or visitors) though I'd rather figure out how to get this working instead of trying to parse `phpinfo()` (which yes, does reveal `short_open_tag` is set to `Off`). Eh... thoughts?

Comment: Yes, if the feature is off, you get an empty string. So you can use `if (ini_get("short_open_tag")) { echo "this server is misconfigured"; }` due to dynamic typing.

Comment: Okay, since I'm carry a lot of responsibility here I'm forced to be a bit of a stickler - is there an official place stating the empty string bit? I always find myself regretting a decision not to verify, that's all.

Comment: I quoted the documentation in my answer; maybe you haven't refreshed to latest edit yet.

Comment: So if you want to be a **real** stickler you can do `if (in_array(strtolower(ini_get("short_open_tag")), ["1", "on"])) { echo "this server is misconfigured"; }` but as I said, I've never seen it return anything but `""`/`"1"` for false/true respectively.

Comment: `#refsect1-function.ini-get-notes` : "A boolean ini value of off will be returned as an empty string" *sigh* totally my bad man, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is a long time late, but I found this and I thought i would add my findings.. If you restart apache or nginx, the change will not take effect, you need to restart php or php-fpm as well.

I have been working on this for over two hours, and I realized I did not restart php8.1-fpm and it worked.  Good luck!

**edit:**
Depending on your system, it could be:
sudo service --status-all | grep fpm << locates your php-fpm

sudo service php-fpm7.4 restart  << restarts service.

or

sudo systemctl | grep fpm << locates your php-fpm

sudo systemctl restart php7.4-fpm.service << restarts service.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide an example code snippet of how to restart php and restart php-fpm or take screenshots of control panels where you would do so

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35086433)

Comment: Hey guess what: this guy helped me. Thanks, Azra.