# Wordpress Error Unclosed '{' in functions.php after migrating to php8

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-error

After updating a website to php8 I got an error and I don't understand it.

An Error of type E_PARSE is found on line 70 /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/DiviChild/functions.php Error-Message: Unclosed '{' on line 47`

```
`function price_table_function() {
ob_start();
$id = get_the_ID();
$uvp = get_field( 'uvp', $id );
$angebot = get_field( 'angebot', $id );
$sale = ($angebot / $uvp)*100;
$saleprice = $uvp - $angebot;?>
<table width="100%" class="price-table">
<tr>
<td>UVP</td>
<td><?php echo $uvp; ?> €</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Reduzierung</td>
<td>-<?php echo $saleprice; ?> €</td>
<tr>
<tr class="sale">
<td>Angebotspreis</td>
<td><?php echo $angebot; ?> € (-<?php echo number_format( $sale, 0, ',', '.' ); ?> %)</td>
<tr>
</table>
<?return ob_get_clean();
}
?>`
```

I don't understand where there is an unclosed '{'

Well it's just a custom function for the website...

Comment: Guessing `<?` short tags are off, change the closing `<?return` code to use `<?php return` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP 8 not revealing short\_open\_tag setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67627159/php-8-not-revealing-short-open-tag-setting)

Comment: For what it's worth, the WordPress coding standards *prohibit* the use of the short versions of php tags `<?` for `<?php`  and `<?=` for `<?php echo`. A good IDE can detect this and whine about it.

Comment: @MarkusAO yes you was right! Short Tags are off. After I turned them on it worked :) Thank you!

Comment: Glad that worked. However, _it would be better practice to change everything to long tags instead_, and turn short tags off.